# Expo EAS Updates Group ID

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

EAS-published updates create a group ID (platform-agnostic) and an update ID (platform-specific). The Updates package (`expo-updates`) only exposes `Updates.updateId` which corresponds to the platform-specific ID. https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/updates/#updatesupdateid

Is there no way to get the current update *group* ID from a running Expo application?

Comment: I'd love to know as well. Either that, or expose the  `iOS update ID` / `Android update ID` in `eas branch:view`. There's now way that I know of at the moment to match the update on a device to a branch update so you can debug.

Answer (score 2):

Just found out that one way to access the `Update group ID` is via [Constants](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/constants/)

```js
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

const updateGroup = Constants.manifest2?.metadata?.["updateGroup"];
```

It feels pretty janky and I wish there was a first class way to do it via Updates but it kinda works for now.